# Display text from img alt tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So far my code is:

```
year = range(1958,2013)
randomYear = random.choice(year)
randomYear = str(randomYear)
page = range(1,5)
randomPage = random.choice(page)
randomPage = str(randomPage)
print(randomPage, randomYear)
url = 'http://www.billboard.com/artists/top-100/'+randomYear+'?page='+randomPage
url1 = urlopen(url)
htmlSource = url1.read()
url1.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)
listm = soup.findAll('article', {'class': 'masonry-brick','style' : 'position;  absolute; top; 0px; left: 0px;'})
for listm in soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'thumbnail'}):
    for listm in soup.find('img alt')(''):
        print(listm)
```

What I want to do is get the img alt='' text. I think I have it correct, somewhat but it displays nothing.

Comment: unrelated: you could use string formatting to create the url: `url = 'http://www.billboard.com/artists/top-100/{year}?page={page}'.format(year=random.randint(1958, 2013), page=random.randint(1, 5))` Note: this code, unlike yours includes both end points.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To get `<img>` elements that have `alt` attribute, you could use `soup('img', alt=True)`:

```
print("\n".join([img['alt'] for img in div.find_all('img', alt=True)]))
```

Do not use the same name for different purposes, it hurts readability of the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlSource)
articles = soup('article', 'masonry-brick',
                style='position;  absolute; top; 0px; left: 0px;')
for div in soup.find_all('div', 'thumbnail'):
    for img in div.find_all('img', alt=True):
        print(img['alt'])
```

Note: `articles` is unused.

> I only need one img tag. How can I do this?

You could use `.find()` method, to get one `<img>` element per `<div>`:

```
for div in soup.find_all('div', 'thumbnail'):
    img = div.find('img', alt=True)
    print(img['alt'])
```

Comment: Right now, that's good. But, I only need one img tag. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you check if I am doing this correctly, it is still showing more than one. `for img in div.find_all('img', alt=True):
        img = div.find('img', alt=True)
        print(img['alt'])`

Comment: @BrianFuller: use `div.find()` *instead* of the `for`-loop.

Comment: `soup.findAll('div',{'class': 'thumbnail'}).img['alt']`

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant:

```
soup.find('img', alt='')
```

This will find an `img` tag with an attribute `alt` with a value of `''` (nothing)

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same issue as before. Displays nothing.

Comment: I should probably add if anyone has misunderstood. I want the text inside of `img alt=''`.

Comment: @BrianFuller It may be an error with your first `findAll`, where there isn't a tag called `'article'` (or something similar, eg there may not be a class `'masonry-brick'`). Upon quick inspection on [one page](http://www.billboard.com/artists/top-100/2012?page=4), I see a lot of `'masonry-brick'` but no tag `'article'`

Comment: @BrianFuller Oh, if you want the text inside, then do `soup.find('img').alt.text`

Comment: I get the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'`

Comment: @BrianFuller That means there is no `alt` in the `img`. You'll probably have to add some conditional: `temp = soup.find('img').alt; if temp is not None: print temp.text`